# Polymorphic relay connections

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I'm using `graphql-js` and `graphql-relay-js` in a project. And I've hit a blocker trying to create a "polymorphic" type.

I have two types, `Activity` and `Checkin`. Each one has a connection to their own version of comments (`ActivityComment` and `CheckinComment`). But each comment type uses the `Commentable` interface.

What I would now like to do is create an interface like `CommentableSource` that both `Activity` and `Checkin` can use so I can build containers that only have to do with comments without having to know about their source. For example:

```
Relay.createContainer(CommentBlock, {
  initialVariables: { amount: 3 },
  fragments: {
    source: () => Relay.QL`fragment on CommentableSource {
      comments(last: $amount) {
        edges {
          node { ${CommentRow.getFragment('commentable') }
        }
      }
    }`,
  },
});
```

But as far as I can tell there's no way to add a connection to an interface. Is this true? If not how would one pull this off?

Thanks!

Comment: This should be possible. Have you received any errors? What's the problem, specifically? If `CommentableSource` has a `comments` field and both `Activity` and `Checkin` implement that field with the same connection type—then you're good. Am I missing something?

Comment: "the same connection type" is the issue. I though all connection types are unique? At least that's the way that `graphql-relay-js` seems to do it. Again I could be the one missing something for sure.

Comment: Oh naa "connection" is just a field with some presets that Relay interprets in a certain way. If you store the connection type and field in variables the you can assign them to both interface implementations. Or you can generate two "different" version of the connection that have the same GraphQL types but data fetch differently.

Comment: Ah, so I just make the `nodeType: Commentable`. Okay I think I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, try it out and take a look at https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/master/src/connection/connection.js and if you have more problems post here.

Comment: Yeah... reviewing the `connection/connection.js` myself here... I think the easiest you can you define your connection type once with `connectionDefinitions()` and in the configuration you pass to that function you can specify `resolve` such that it that fetches the appropriate comment—an activity or checkin  comment—depending on the actual runtime parent type.

Comment: If you resolved that on your own, don't forget to add it as answer.